# parsing a file to create objects in java

Tags: java

I have a file with is the output of an trading agent's activities. For example:

```
222666:org.powertac.common.Order::171875::new::21::165482::-35.74395569719625::35.0
222666:org.powertac.common.Order::171876::new::21::165893::-35.74395569719625::35.0
```

The class `Order` is defined as:

```
  public Order (Broker broker, Timeslot timeslot,
                double mWh, Double limitPrice)
  {
    super();
    this.broker = broker;
    this.timeslot = timeslot;
    this.mWh = mWh;
    this.limitPrice = limitPrice;
  }
```

so from the file I have:

```
<id>:<package_name>::<execution_id>::<new object>::<args_list>
```

However, there is some examples like:

```
222665:org.powertac.genco.Genco::21::setCurrentCapacity::35.74395569719625
222665:org.powertac.genco.Genco::21::setInOperation::true
```

so instead of creating a `new` object, I have to call the method `setCurrentCapacity` with the `35.7439..` parameter.
My goal is to create a

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new Map<Integer, Object>();
```

that's it, a `Map` between `Integer id` and `Object`. Thus, if I want to reproduce the agent activity again, I would just process the `Map` Object. I was wondering what would be the best approach to achieve my goal. Do I have to actually create the `Genco` object, for example, and cast it to `Object` before storing on the `Map`?  How do I set the function call? I mean, how do I create the `Genco` object and tell it to call `setInOperation` in the `Map`? Also, what does it mean and how could I handle values like:

```
300:org.powertac.du.DefaultBrokerService$LocalBroker::1::new::default broker
300:org.powertac.du.DefaultBrokerService$LocalBroker::1::setLocal::true
```

with the `$` symbol?

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is a valid character in a class name, but by convention its use is discouraged.  In practice, it can show up for numerous reasons.  In your scenario, it is likely that `LocalBroker` is an inner class of `DefaultBrokerService`.

From the [JLS§3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.

Answer (score 0):

> **I was wondering what would be the best approach to achieve my goal. Do
>   I have to actually create the Genco object, for example, and cast it
>   to Object before storing on the Map?**

Genco is already an Object. You don't need to cast it. All classes inherits from Object in Java. Just insert it in the map.

```
yourMap.put( 1234, gencoObj );
```

> **I mean, how do I create the Genco object and tell it to call
>   setInOperation in the Map?**

Get the object via its id (your map key), cast it to the apropriate type and call the desired method.

```
Object o = yourMap.get( 1234 );
if ( o instanceof Genco ) {
    Genco g = ( Genco ) o;
    g.methodToBeCalled();
}
```

The `$` sign is used by the Java compiler to name nested classes. So, in your case, `LocalBroker` is a nested class of `DefaultBrokerService`.

Compiling this:

```
public class Foo {
    private class Bar {
    }
}
```

Will generate two .class files: `Foo.class` and `Foo$Bar.class`.

**Edit:** to store the method parameters you can do something like:

```
// considering this class
public class Genco {
    ...
    public void methodToBeCalled( Double param ) {
        // do something
    }
}


// in another class...
// storing the parameters using a String as a key
// representing the object id + the name of the method to be called
Map<String, Object[]> params = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();

// for methodToBeCalled of the object with id equals to 1234
// store a new array of objects with an 2.5 Double (autoboxing will apply here, i.e., 
// the double 2.5 will be wrapped in a Double
params.put( "1234-methodToBeCalled", new Object[]{ 2.5 } );


// now, using...
int objectId = 1234;

// get the object
Object o = yourMap.get( objectId );

// verify if it is an instance of Genco
if ( o instanceof Genco ) {

    // yes, it is, so cast it to Genco to be able
    // to call Genco specific methods
    Genco g = ( Genco ) o;

    // getting the parameters (objectId + method name)
    Object p = params.get( objectId + "-methodToBeCalled" );

    // calling the method, passing the first value of the stored array (2.5)
    g.methodToBeCalled( ( Double ) p[0] );

}
```

Comment: David, if the method to be called has arguments, how do I give those arguments to the object `Genco`, and them call the object? For example, `Genco` has to call a `callMeMaybe( double value )` method, how do I store the method to be called( `callMeMaybe` ) in the `Map` data structure

Comment: You can use a second map to store the method parameters. If the ids are different among all types of objects, you can use an in to be the map key. As the value, you will set an array of objects with the parameters. I will update my answer.

Comment: So let me see if i got the high level:
In the first map I push `< id, Object >` regardless of the outcome ...

Comment: Yep. The first map will be your object container. Like a symbol table.

Comment: And how do I create an `Object` from a `String` in `Java`? If I were in `PHP` I would do:
`$name = "Name"; $me = new $name();`, but how is it done in `Java`?

Comment: You can verify what object you want to create (comparing the String and calling the desired constructor) or creating some reflective code.